# Getting issues while adding a external library(libcurl) in c++ with vs code

Tags: c++, dll, include, libcurl, include-path

I'm new in programming. I'm working on a project where I need a external library libcurl. After building my code it shows 'builded successfully' but when I run it it shows this error:

```
    fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
    const char* smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com";
    const int smtp_port = 587;
    ... ... ...
```

I have libcurl package properly in my system. I think I have configured my c_cpp_properties.json and task.json properly.

```
//c_cpp_properties.json
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Users\\istea\\Downloads\\libcurl\\include"
```

```
//task.json
   "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-lcurl",
                "-IC:\\Users\\istea\\Downloads\\libcurl\\include",
                "-LC:\\Users\\istea\\Downloads\\libcurl\\lib"
```

Comment: VSCode is a very advanced, complex development tool that's designed for highly skilled, experienced developers who have a wide range of domain knowledge, like the JSON configuration syntax, and familiarity with obscure compiler flags and options. It is not meant to be used for people who are just starting out learning C++ and who do not have established development experience, those people will find other development environments, like VS community edition (Windows) or emacs+make (Linux, MacOS), easier to use. Give them a try, instead.

Comment: `-IC:\\Users\\istea\\Downloads\\libcurl\\include` You don't seem to follow the official vscode installer guide for C++. If you had follow it, you would install curl library with the MSYS2 pacman.